# Do you know of a JavaScript widget for Solar Hijridates?

Tags: javascript, widget

Do you know of a JavaScript widget for Solar Hijri (Jalali) dates?  Users will likely enter dates as Solar Hijri and I need to convert.

Comment: Please see here to convert any Islamic calendar to Gregorian Date without using libraries or complex formulas:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222556/how-to-convert-any-of-the-5-islamic-hijri-calendars-dates-to-any-of-18-world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find an LGPL licensed Javascript implementation for converting dates back and forth here:

http://www.farsiweb.info/jalali/jalali.js

Comment: Thanks you!  (+1)  Any chance you know of a GUI widget that I might drop into my code?

Comment: @Upper: Not really, but you can quite easily modify an existing GUI widget based on Gregorian calendar to one that uses Persian calendar.