# obtain date object from year, month and day in other locale in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, locale, ecmascript-temporal

I have year, month and day like:

```
let dt = '1401/01/01'
```

in locale like:

```
let locale = 'fa-IR'
```

how can create a date object from it without using some libraries?

something like:

```
new Date(dt,locale)
```

Comment: Careful with your spelling of "JavaScript" to avoid collisions with "Java".

Comment: "fa-IR" is a BCP47 language code, not a locale, which might be Tehran or other place.

Comment: The [ECMAScript *Date* object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-objects) only supports the proleptic Gregorian calendar. If you want to parse or produce dates for any other calendar, you will have to either write your own parse and format functions, or use a library, though the *Intl.DateTimeFormat* constructor can help with formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) API, which is soon to be part of JavaScript, can help with this use case.

While Temporal currently requires a polyfill (see list of Temporal [polyfills](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal#polyfills) here), Temporal is currently being implemented in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.) so in the not-too-distant future there will be no polyfill needed.

Assuming that you're using the `persian` calendar (see list of supported calendars [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/calendar)) you can do something like this:

```js
// Temporal polyfill. See https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal#polyfills
// has a list of actively-developed polyfills.
// Replace this import with whatever is required by your favorite polyfill.
import { Temporal } from '@js-temporal/polyfill';

let dt = '1401/01/01';
const [year, month, day] = dt.split('/');

// Create a Temporal.PlainDate object, interpreting year, month, and day
// according to the Persian calendar.
const date = Temporal.PlainDate.from({year, month, day, calendar: 'persian'});

// Format this date in Farsi, using the Persian calendar
console.log (date.toLocaleString('fa-IR', { calendar:'persian' }));
// => ۱۴۰۱/۱/۱

// Format this date in English, using the Persian calendar
console.log (date.toLocaleString('en-IR', { calendar:'persian' }));
// => 1/1/1401 AP

// Format this date in English, using the Gregorian calendar
console.log (date.withCalendar('gregory').toLocaleString('en-US', { calendar:'gregory' }));
// => 3/21/2022

// Format this date into a cross-platform, computer-readable format
console.log (date.toString());
// => 2022-03-21[u-ca=persian]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

It seems the question is about Islamic (Hijri) Calendar Dates, which unfortunately I do not know a whole lot about.

However it seems the JavaScript `Date` object will present difficulties as it specifies an object measured by the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970. And so its basis is in the Gregorian calendar system.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) also notes on the `Date.parse()` method only supports the [ISO 8601 format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format), which also seems like it presents a problem for the different calendars.

There is also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222556/how-to-convert-any-of-the-5-islamic-hijri-calendars-dates-to-any-of-18-world) on Stack Overflow that seems to work on a very similar problem using the `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` to work between the two calendars, and may provide the answer needed by OP here.

Lastly, a new method for dates in JavaScript [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) is (as of September 29, 2022) still  in ***Stage 3 proposal***, but likely will become part of the spec in the near future. It seems `Temporal` fixes a lot of the short-comings of the `Date` object and should allow for what OP is asking here (*as the calendar can be specified*)

### Original Answer (*invalid*)

The JavaScript `Date` object does not take a locale as a parameter. However you can use methods like `toLocaleString` and `toLocaleDateString` to output a date in a certain locale.

So if you just want to create a `Date` object, you only need to pass in the date/time:

```
let dt = new Date("1401/01/01");
```

From there, you can preform any date related calculations or methods on the newly created `Date` object. If you need to output the date in a particular locale you can use `toLocaleString`:

```
let dt = new Date("1401/01/01");
console.log(dt.toLocaleString("fa-IR"));
```

Comment: as you see "1401/01/01" is in another locale and putting it inside Date create a wrong equvalent date in gregorian(1401 is in hijri shamsi)

Comment: @kingofday What date is it supposed to be and what is it showing up as for you? I am not able to replicate what you claim.

Comment: @kingofday I have updated my answer. Unfortunately I don't know much about the Hijri date system. I did link to another Stack Overflow topic that seems to be able to convert between Hijri and Gregorian and this may be able to help you. By default it seems the JavaScript `Date` object doesn't work with Hijri Calendar dates though.

Comment: "*MDN also notes on the Date.parse() method only supports the ISO 8601 format*". MDN is wrong about that. [*Date.parse*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.parse) supports 3 formats, i.e. those produced by *toISOString*, *toString* and *toUTCString*.

Comment: from locale i mean what been used in "Intl" of javascript that convert a date object with format to another calendar, but not vise versa, thank you for your answer